# Outlook strips out safe senders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, spam-prevention, email-client

I am a software engineer and wrote a Web API that has system generated mail messages that get sent when a user "requests more info" on the website.  This generates 2 messages, one on the requester side and one on the corporate side to provide the internal team contact info for the person requesting.

The message generates fine and the one that gets sent to the user side (the person requesting info) arrives without issue.  The one that gets sent to the corporate side also generates fine, however, it always goes to junk mail.

We use GoDaddy for the email account.  I have tried adding this address (the sender is the same as the receiver) and the domain to safe senders in outlook web app but the validation won't allow me to add it.  Instead, I configured it in outlook desktop

> Junk email options > Safe Senders tab > Add

and it does work for a period of time and then it gets stripped out of safe sender after a few minutes.

Wut do?

Comment: Have you discussed this with the people who manage email for the corporation?  It might be happening at the mail server level.

Comment: This issue maybe related to your email account server. You can configured other email account on your Outlook client to confirm whether the Junk option feature works fine in your Outlook.

Comment: @DanBracuk we use Godaddy for the email account.  There is no enterprise exchange server so if this were the case it would be on GoDaddy's side.  I was able to access the exchange settings through the GoDaddy interface, which has a link to Exchange settings but I could not find any settings related to junk mail.  Will update the post with screenshots shortly.

Comment: @DanBracuk it appears you were correct! modifying the default settings on the protection > spam filter seems to have fixed it!  Waiting now to see if the settings stick.